# Why doesn't this JDBC select return any rows?

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I have the following SQL statement which I am trying to execute via JDBC PreparedStatement:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM offsets sto WHERE sto.done = 0 AND sto.instance_index = 1
```

In my database this happily returns 1 row as it should.

But once I execute it in a JdbcTemplate:

```
private final String selectSql = "SELECT TOP(1) * " +
            "FROM offsets sto " +
            "WHERE sto.done = 0 " +
            "AND sto.instance_index = ? ";

template.query(selectSql, new Object[]{1}, new int[]{Types.INTEGER} ,rs -> {

    Offset offset = new Offset();
    offset.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
    offset.setInstance_index(rs.getInt("instance_index"));
    offset.setDone(rs.getBoolean("done"));

    return Optional.of(offset);

});
```

I get :

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetHasCurrentRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:563) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getterGetColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:2046) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre11.jar:na]
```

What is going on? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resultset starts before the first returned row.  Call

```
 rs.next();
 Offset offset = new Offset();
 offset.setId(rs.getLong("id")); 
 . . .
```

> boolean next()
>
> throws SQLException
>
> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. **A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned
> before the first row**; the first call to the method next makes the
> first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the
> current row, and so on. When a call to the next method returns false,
> the cursor is positioned after the last row.

[Resultset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: I was actually confusing it with RowMapper.